# python - appending a class object to list in another class

Tags: python, class

i m being ask to create a python program that contains a class Fleur(flower) and a class Bouquet , and each flower class contains a name and price and other arguments , and the bouquet class contains the the objects from the flower class under the form of a list , i m having a problem with how to add the flowers to the list of bouquet and manipulate that list . thank you

```
class Fleur :
    def __init__(self, name ,couleur, prix _base, parfum_=False, promotion=False):
        self. n=name
        self  .c=couleur
        self. px=prix _base
        self.pa=parfum_
        self.pr=promotion
    def prix(self):
        if self.pr==True:
            return self. px*0.5
        else:
            return self. px
    def parfum(self):
        return self.pa
    def affiche(self):
        if self.pa==True :
            a=self.n,self.c,'parfumée , prix:', self  .prix(),'MAD'
            print(a)
        else:
            a=self .n ,self .c,', prix:', self .prix(),'MAD'
            print(a)
    @staticmethod
    def equal(A,B):
        if A. n==B .n and A. c==B .c and A.pa==B.pa:
            return True 
        else:
            return False 
class Bouquet:
    def __init__(self):
        self .bouquet=[]
    def ajouter(self, f):
        self .bouquet. append(f. affiche())
```

this is as far as i went

Comment: please format your post appropriately.

Comment: `f.affiche()` doesn't return anything (returns `None`), so `None` will be appended to your list when you do `self .bouquet. append(f. affiche())`. You want to do `self.bouquet.append(f)`

Comment: Also note that you don't need to compare to `True` in `if self.pa==True`. The equivalent is `if self.pa:`. Similarly, the `if...else...` in `equal(A, B)` can be replaced simply with `return A.n == B.n and A.c == B.c and A.pa == B.pa`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi , when i m using   self. bouquet . append(f) i get None as output , and in equal function i have to use it , i have a list of function that have to be in my code . thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the method `ajouter` for the class `Bouquet` it looks like you are appending `f.affiche()` but `affiche()` does not return anything. The method affiche prints the output a so the value it returns is `None`. If you want to be able to append the output of affiche for a given f, you would need to return a in affiche, or just return what would have been set as the value for a.

The code might look something like this.

```py
    def affiche(self):
        if self.pa == True:
            return self.n, self.c,'parfumée , prix:', self.prix(), 'MAD'
        else:
            return self.n, self.c, ', prix:', self.prix(), 'MAD'
```

Comment: They probably want to append the `Fleur` instance to the bouquet, not a tuple containing some properties of the instance.

Comment: thank you for your answer , the problem is that i m obliged to use print not return in affiche , is there any other way to do that ? . thank you

Comment: Yea, if you need it to print, do what Pranav Hosangadi suggested and append(f), then in Bouquet call bouquet[x].affiche() with the original affiche, and x being the index of what flower you want to print.

Comment: @Jake i have tried to do as  Pranav Hosangadi suggested but still it dose not work

Comment: @yahyababa what's not working, is it the storing of the instances of Fleur in bouquet = [] or calling the affiche method after?

Comment: @Jake when i print(b1)   (b1 being the list of Bouquet class that contains a flower) i get "<__main__.Bouquet object at 0x000001EF10D043C8>" as an output